# ListView Virtualization cause Control to get wrong state

Tags: c#, windows, win-universal-app, uwp

I've created a simple control to preview thumbnail images and display the full image if it is downloaded. This control is nested in a ListView. However if the ListView is scrolled the Items will be recycled but my control won't remain in the correct state. It will display the Preview even if the image is downloaded and remain not clickable. Can someone explain me what i am doing wrong? All data is bound to the control.

```
[TemplateVisualState(Name = "Preview", GroupName = "ControlStates")]
[TemplateVisualState(Name = "Fullview", GroupName = "ControlStates")]
public class Attachment : Control
{

    public ImageSource Image
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageProperty, value); }
    }
    public static DependencyProperty ImageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Image", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(Attachment), new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback((A, B) => ((Attachment)A).OnImageChanged())));
    private void OnImageChanged()
    {
        if (Image == null)
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Preview", true);
        else
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Fullview", true);
    }

    public ImageSource Thumbnail
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ThumbnailProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ThumbnailProperty, value); }
    }
    public static DependencyProperty ThumbnailProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Thumbnail", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(Attachment), new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback((A, B) => ((Attachment)A).OnThumbnailChanged())));
    private void OnThumbnailChanged()
    {
        if (Image == null)
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Preview", true);
        else
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Fullview", true);
    }


    public bool IsAttachmentDownloading
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsAttachmentDownloadingProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsAttachmentDownloadingProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsAttachmentDownloadingProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsAttachmentDownloading", typeof(bool), typeof(Attachment), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    public ICommand DownloadAttachment
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(DownloadAttachmentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DownloadAttachmentProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DownloadAttachmentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DownloadAttachment", typeof(ICommand), typeof(Attachment), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public object DownloadAttachmentParameter
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(DownloadAttachmentParameterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DownloadAttachmentParameterProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DownloadAttachmentParameterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DownloadAttachmentParameter", typeof(object), typeof(Attachment), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public object DownloadAttachmentContent
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(DownloadAttachmentContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DownloadAttachmentContentProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DownloadAttachmentContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DownloadAttachmentContent", typeof(object), typeof(Attachment), new PropertyMetadata(null));


    Button _DownloadAttachmentButton = null;

    public Attachment()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(Attachment);
        this.Loaded += Attachment_Loaded;
    }

    private void Attachment_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Image == null)
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Preview", true);
        else
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Fullview", true);
    }

    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        //this._DownloadAttachmentButton = GetTemplateChild("PART_DownloadAttachmentButton") as Button;
    }
}


<Style TargetType="local:Attachment">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:Attachment">
                <Border x:Name="PART_Border" Opacity="1">
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                        <Grid x:Name="PART_ThumbContainer" Opacity="1">
                            <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                            <Image x:Name="PART_Thumb" Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="{TemplateBinding Thumbnail}"/>
                            <Button Command="{TemplateBinding DownloadAttachment}" BorderThickness="0" Background="#AA000000"
                                    CommandParameter="{TemplateBinding DownloadAttachmentParameter}" 
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="&#xE118;" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Margin="0,0,5,0"
                                               Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" 
                                               FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding DownloadAttachmentContent}"
                                               Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" 
                                               FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" 
                                               FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid x:Name="PART_ImageContainer" Opacity="0">
                            <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                            <Image x:Name="PART_Image" Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="{TemplateBinding Image}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ControlStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Preview">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PART_ThumbContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PART_ImageContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Fullview">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PART_ThumbContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PART_ImageContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: If i remove the VisualStates and handle the opacity in code the view works flawless.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you should call code responsible for state changing in `OnApplyTemplate` too. I mean:

```
protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();

     if (Image == null)
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Preview", true);
    else
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Fullview", true);
}
```

Probably, after control is recycled and showed again, `OnApplyTemplate` is launched. Check it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if i got time i will give this a shot.